# When is a power of a sum of powers a sum of powers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, diophantine-equations

For which natural numbers $a,b,p$ with $a>b>0$ do we have
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^a\right)^p
=
\sum_{k=1}^nk^b
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$?
This is famously true for $(a,b,p)=(1,3,2)$, but looking at lists of sums of powers shows no other examples.
How many "solutions" $(a,b,p)$ are there and what are they?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292636/other-variation-of-nicomachuss-theorem

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1869843/11619)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I hadn't seen that one, but it seems to be only a partial version of this one ($a=1$).

Comment: @mathlove, questions like this are hard to find... Should we close this one as a duplicate?

Comment: True, Joonas. Not a perfect match. The technique is still similar.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: All I can say is that your question is a partial version of the linked question where $p$ is rational.

Answer (score 2):

There are no other examples.

For large $n$ we have<sup>1</sup>
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk^b=\frac1{b+1}n^{b+1}+O(n^b).
$$
Looking at leading order terms only gives the constraints $p(a+1)=b+1$ (for the power) and $(a+1)^p=b+1$ (for the coefficient).
In particular, this gives $p(a+1)=(a+1)^p$, or $p=(a+1)^{p-1}$.

Since $a\geq1$, we have $p=(a+1)^{p-1}\geq2^{p-1}$.
But $p\geq2^{p-1}$ only holds for $p\leq2$.
(In other words, $\sqrt[p-1]{p}$ is not an integer when $p\geq3$.)
It is now easy to see that there is no solution if $a\geq2$.
The case $p=1$ (with $a=b$) is uninteresting and was excluded in the question, so the only option is $p=2$ and $a=1$.
This leaves $b=3$.

(I didn't find the answer anywhere, so I decided to ask and answer myself. I hope others agree that this is a fun observation.)

---

<sup>1</sup>
One can argue this by comparing the sum to an integral or by using [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula).