# Does $\mathop{\LARGEΣ}_{k = 1}^{n}k^α = \left(\mathop{\LARGEΣ}_{k = 1}^{n}k\right)^β$ for which $α \neq 3, \ β \neq 2$ and $α \neq β$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I figured out that:

> $$\mathop{\LARGEΣ}_{k = 1}^{n}k^3 = \bigg(\mathop{\LARGEΣ}_{k = 1}^{n}k\bigg)^2$$

Are there any other solutions for the following equation, for which $α \neq 3, \ β \neq 2$ and $α \neq β$?

> > $$\mathop{\LARGEΣ}_{k = 1}^{n}k^α = \bigg(\mathop{\LARGEΣ}_{k = 1}^{n}k\bigg)^β$$

P.S. The Sigmas in the equations look different to how its font usually looks like on the MSE and/or MO, (it's *typical* look appearing like this $\rightarrow \sum$) because I am using

**\mathop{\LARGEΣ}_{k = 1}^{n}**

just to test how it looks like, and because of its *boldness*, I don't mind its appearance.

---

**Edit:**

There is another answer that solves my problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1869843/are-there-a-b-in-mathbbn-that-sum-k-1n-ka-sum-k-1n-kb-b), mentioned by [*mathlove*](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/78967/mathlove).

Comment: @GabrielRomon so for example, let $α = 69$ then this implies that $β = 35$?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1869843/are-there-a-b-in-mathbbn-that-sum-k-1n-ka-sum-k-1n-kb-b) or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292636/other-variation-of-nicomachuss-theorem).

Comment: @mathlove oh sweet Jesus this is a duplicate....a *very* similar dup. And I just figured that $α = β = 1$ is of course a solution so I edited the question. I wonder why nobody mentioned that prior to this comment...

Comment: Yes, and I never realised this was associated with *Nicomachus' Theorem*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle \left(\sum_{k=1}^nk \right)^\beta  = \left( \frac{n(n+1)}2 \right)^\beta\sim\frac{n^{2\beta}}{2^\beta}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k^\alpha \sim \frac{n^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}$, two necessary conditions for the equality to hold for all $n$ are

- $\alpha+1 = 2\beta$
- $2^\beta=\alpha+1$

This implies $2\beta =2^\beta$, hence $\beta \in \{1,2\}$.

Conversely, $(\alpha, \beta)=(1,1)$ and $(\alpha, \beta)=(3,2)$ are indeed solutions.

Comment: Sorry I cannot vote $(+1)$ because I reached my limit....but I can do this $$\color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Answer (score 1):

Everything here can be put into semi-closed form. $\sum_{k=1}^n k = n(n+1)/2$ and for $\alpha>3$ odd, $\sum_{k=1}^n k^\alpha = n^2(n+1)^2/2\cdot g(n)$ where $g(n)$ is not of the form $(n(n+1)/2)^\beta$ for any $\beta$. For $\alpha$ even, a similar case occurs. So the only case we have equality is $\alpha,\beta=1$ and the case you mentioned.

Comment: Why for $g(n)$? What does $g(n)$ mean?

Comment: You can prove it using an inductive argument. Consider the series $\sum_{i=1}^n (n+1)^k-n^k$ which is telescoping, so more precisely $(n+1)^k-1$. Then apply binomial theorem to both sides and apply induction. This is probably more hectic than the proof in the other post.